Пустое окно после сборки
После сборки моего кода появляется пустое окно, помогите.
Код Form1.cs.
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting;

namespace DataAnalyzer
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private List<DataEntry> dataEntries;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();  // Инициализация компонентов формы
            InitializeCustomComponents();  // Инициализация дополнительных компонентов
        }

        private void InitializeCustomComponents()
        {
            dataEntries = new List<DataEntry>();

            // Настройка Chart
            chart1.ChartAreas.Add(new ChartArea("MainChartArea"));

            // Настройка кнопок
            btnLoadFile.Click += BtnLoadFile_Click;
            btnSaveCharts.Click += BtnSaveCharts_Click;

            // Инициализация OpenFileDialog
            openFileDialog.Filter = "Text files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";

            // Инициализация SaveFileDialog
            saveFileDialog.Filter = "PNG Image|*.png|All files|*.*";
            saveFileDialog.FileOk += new CancelEventHandler(saveFileDialog_FileOk); // Обработчик события FileOk
        }

        private void BtnLoadFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                LoadData(openFileDialog.FileName);
                BuildCharts();
            }
        }

        private void BtnSaveCharts_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (saveFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                chart1.SaveImage(saveFileDialog.FileName, ChartImageFormat.Png);
            }
        }

        private void LoadData(string filePath)
        {
            dataEntries.Clear();
            var lines = File.ReadAllLines(filePath);
            foreach (var line in lines)
            {
                var parts = line.Split(';');
                if (parts.Length == 15)
                {
                    var entry = new DataEntry
                    {
                        TeamID = parts[0],
                        Time = int.Parse(parts[1]),
                        Pressure = int.Parse(parts[2]),
                        Temperature = int.Parse(parts[3]),
                        Altitude = int.Parse(parts[4]),
                        Accel1 = int.Parse(parts[5]),
                        Accel2 = int.Parse(parts[6]),
                        Accel3 = int.Parse(parts[7]),
                        Gyro1 = int.Parse(parts[8]),
                        Gyro2 = int.Parse(parts[9]),
                        Gyro3 = int.Parse(parts[10]),
                        Flag1 = int.Parse(parts[11]),
                        Flag2 = int.Parse(parts[12]),
                        Flag3 = int.Parse(parts[13]),
                        Flag4 = int.Parse(parts[14])
                    };
                    dataEntries.Add(entry);
                }
            }
        }

        private void BuildCharts()
        {
            chart1.Series.Clear();

            // Высота от времени
            var altitudeSeries = new Series("Altitude vs Time")
            {
                ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line
            };
            altitudeSeries.Points.DataBindXY(dataEntries.Select(x => x.Time).ToList(), dataEntries.Select(x => x.Altitude).ToList());
            chart1.Series.Add(altitudeSeries);

            // Давление от времени
            var pressureSeries = new Series("Pressure vs Time")
            {
                ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line
            };
            pressureSeries.Points.DataBindXY(dataEntries.Select(x => x.Time).ToList(), dataEntries.Select(x => x.Pressure).ToList());
            chart1.Series.Add(pressureSeries);

            // Высота от температуры
            var altitudeTempSeries = new Series("Altitude vs Temperature")
            {
                ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line
            };
            altitudeTempSeries.Points.DataBindXY(dataEntries.Select(x => x.Temperature).ToList(), dataEntries.Select(x => x.Altitude).ToList());
            chart1.Series.Add(altitudeTempSeries);

            // Акселерометр по трем осям от времени
            var accel1Series = new Series("Accel1 vs Time")
            {
                ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line
            };
            accel1Series.Points.DataBindXY(dataEntries.Select(x => x.Time).ToList(), dataEntries.Select(x => x.Accel1).ToList());
            chart1.Series.Add(accel1Series);

            var accel2Series = new Series("Accel2 vs Time")
            {
                ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line
            };
            accel2Series.Points.DataBindXY(dataEntries.Select(x => x.Time).ToList(), dataEntries.Select(x => x.Accel2).ToList());
            chart1.Series.Add(accel2Series);

            var accel3Series = new Series("Accel3 vs Time")
            {
                ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line
            };
            accel3Series.Points.DataBindXY(dataEntries.Select(x => x.Time).ToList(), dataEntries.Select(x => x.Accel3).ToList());
            chart1.Series.Add(accel3Series);

            // Гироскоп по трем осям от времени
            var gyro1Series = new Series("Gyro1 vs Time")
            {
                ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line
            };
            gyro1Series.Points.DataBindXY(dataEntries.Select(x => x.Time).ToList(), dataEntries.Select(x => x.Gyro1).ToList());
            chart1.Series.Add(gyro1Series);

            var gyro2Series = new Series("Gyro2 vs Time")
            {
                ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line
            };
            gyro2Series.Points.DataBindXY(dataEntries.Select(x => x.Time).ToList(), dataEntries.Select(x => x.Gyro2).ToList());
            chart1.Series.Add(gyro2Series);

            var gyro3Series = new Series("Gyro3 vs Time")
            {
                ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line
            };
            gyro3Series.Points.DataBindXY(dataEntries.Select(x => x.Time).ToList(), dataEntries.Select(x => x.Gyro3).ToList());
            chart1.Series.Add(gyro3Series);
        }

        private void saveFileDialog_FileOk(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            // Обработка события FileOk
            // Здесь можно добавить дополнительную логику, если необходимо
        }
    }

    public class DataEntry
    {
        public string TeamID { get; set; }
        public int Time { get; set; }
        public int Pressure { get; set; }
        public int Temperature { get; set; }
        public int Altitude { get; set; }
        public int Accel1 { get; set; }
        public int Accel2 { get; set; }
        public int Accel3 { get; set; }
        public int Gyro1 { get; set; }
        public int Gyro2 { get; set; }
        public int Gyro3 { get; set; }
        public int Flag1 { get; set; }
        public int Flag2 { get; set; }
        public int Flag3 { get; set; }
        public int Flag4 { get; set; }
    }
}

Код Form.Designer.cs.
namespace DataAnalyzer
{
    partial class Form1
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Обязательная переменная конструктора.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Освободить все используемые ресурсы.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true, если управляемый ресурс должен быть удален; в противном случае false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Код, автоматически созданный конструктором форм Windows

        /// <summary>
        /// Требуемый метод для поддержки конструктора — не изменяйте 
        /// содержимое этого метода с помощью редактора кода.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.btnLoadFile = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.btnSaveCharts = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.chart1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart();
            this.openFileDialog = new System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog();
            this.saveFileDialog = new System.Windows.Forms.SaveFileDialog();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.chart1)).BeginInit();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // btnLoadFile
            // 
            this.btnLoadFile.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 12);
            this.btnLoadFile.Name = "btnLoadFile";
            this.btnLoadFile.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
            this.btnLoadFile.TabIndex = 0;
            this.btnLoadFile.Text = "Load File";
            this.btnLoadFile.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            // 
            // btnSaveCharts
            // 
            this.btnSaveCharts.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(93, 12);
            this.btnSaveCharts.Name = "btnSaveCharts";
            this.btnSaveCharts.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(93, 23);
            this.btnSaveCharts.TabIndex = 1;
            this.btnSaveCharts.Text = "Save Charts";
            this.btnSaveCharts.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            // 
            // chart1
            // 
            this.chart1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 43);
            this.chart1.Name = "chart1";
            this.chart1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(776, 395);
            this.chart1.TabIndex = 2;
            this.chart1.Text = "chart1";
            // 
            // openFileDialog
            // 
            this.openFileDialog.FileName = "openFileDialog";
            // 
            // saveFileDialog
            // 
            this.saveFileDialog.FileOk += new System.ComponentModel.CancelEventHandler(this.saveFileDialog_FileOk);
            // 
            // Form1
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(8F, 16F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(800, 450);
            this.Controls.Add(this.chart1);
            this.Controls.Add(this.btnSaveCharts);
            this.Controls.Add(this.btnLoadFile);
            this.Name = "Form1";
            this.Text = "Data Analyzer";
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.chart1)).EndInit();
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }

        #endregion

        private System.Windows.Forms.Button btnLoadFile;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button btnSaveCharts;
        private System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart chart1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog openFileDialog;
        private System.Windows.Forms.SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog;
    }
}


Что значит пустое окно? Данных нет или кнопок жаже нет, или что? А до сборки не пустое? Давайте подробнее.

@aepot , полностью пустое окно. Скрин: https://imgur.com/a/GHEQqAg

Добавьте этот скрин в вопрос. Вы уверены, что запустили верный экзешник? Быть может попробовать всё закрыть и пересобрать приложение (Rebuild)? Program.cs не трогали?
